# @JsonView declaration for whole Spring MVC rest controler

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson, json-view

Is there some way how I can declare `@JsonView` for whole Spring MVC rest controller?

I know I can declare `@JsonView` for particular method like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.G
 @JsonView(User.WithoutPasswordView.class)
 public User getUser() {
      return new User("eric", "7!jd#h23");
 }
```

But I don't want to define `@JsonView` per method because my methods are defined in supper class and I don't want to override them just to add single annotation.
I would like to declare `@JsonView` for whole controller i.e. like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(ZONES_PATH)
@JsonView(User.WithoutPasswordView.class)
public class ZoneResource extends GenericRestService<Zone> {
     ...
```

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: You resolved the problem? I'm in the same situation. :)

Comment: I've abandoned `@JsonView`. They are problematic and confusing. It seems cleaner to define specific transfer objects and e.g. use mappers.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can use mapper for solve this problem? You can recommend me a useful link? Thanks!

Comment: You just simply define ne object which is same as the original object, but contains only properties you want to include. Map original object to new object using e.g. MapStruct (http://mapstruct.org/). return that new object.

Answer (score 1):

create custom object mapper that will use pre-defined view

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        super();
        setSerializationConfig(getSerializationConfig()
                .withView(User.WithoutPasswordView.class));
    }
}
```

register it as default object mapper used by spring

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>        
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>        
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.web.CustomObjectMapper" />
```

Comment: That is interesting idea, but wouldn't it define `@JsonView` for whole application? I need it scoped only for particular REST Controller.

Comment: Yes and for the whole Spring MVC controller. You can also do it like this `mapper.writer().withView(User.WithoutPasswordView.class).writeValueAsString(myEntityWithView);`. Annotations cannot be inherited but method can